# Correct way to use dynamic sized types in chain extension

Tags: ink, types, chain-extension, contracts, pallet-contracts

I'm writing chain extensions for my pallets and I have a few functions that require dynamic sized types, for example `Vec<u8>` for metadata and `Vec<u64>` for a list of asset ids.

The way I am approaching this right now is to make an array filled with zeroes in the size of the boundaries set for those cases in the runtime and fill the beginning with the actual data in the contract, then send it to the chain extension like that and removing the trailing zeroes.

Sure this works, but it cannot be the best possible approach and I'm struggling to find any resource on chain extensions. There's a short documentation page and an example that shows the very minimum, only deals with a single function that has a single fixed size argument.

So yeah, what I'm looking for here is a better approach to dynamic sized types in chain extensions but I'd really appreciate any resources and actual code for me to take a look.

Comment: If possible, storing a fixed sized hash of the value might be better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to read memory from a contract you should check out the different functions on the [`Environment`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/struct.Environment.html) type. As Green Baneling already pointed out correctly you should use SCALE in order to encode and decode types from and to contract memory.

As you already noticed the `read_as` function is only meant for types where the size is known at compile time. In your case you should use `env.read_as_unbounded(len: u32)`. The `len` passed by the contract can be read by calling `env.in_len()`.

Comment: Could you provide some examples of this usage and their counterparts in the contract side? I've been experimenting a lot with read() and read_as_unbounded() while also sending the lengths of the encoded types as the first arguments, but all my tries resulted in encoding failed errors when attempting to call those functions.

Comment: I mean "decoding" failed errors

Comment: Oh I see now, I don't have to encode things myself on the contract side. I was doing that and encoded data was being sent with double encoding. I managed to get things working, but I still believe documentation and proper example code is very lacking for this.

Comment: Documentation could always be better of course. But did you check out all the resources?: [1](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/index.html) [2](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/tree/master/examples/rand-extension) [3](https://paritytech.github.io/ink-docs/macros-attributes/chain-extension/)

Answer (score 2):

Each type in ink! implements `scale::Encode` and `scale::Decode`. That serialization and deserialization are used across the substrate everywhere. To pass some dynamic types you can encode it on the contract side and decode it on the extension side.

Comment: But on the runtime side the chain_extension types need to implement MaxEncodedLen to be read from memory:
`let a: Vec<u8> = env.read_as()?;` -> `the trait 'MaxEncodedLen' is not implemented for 'hidden_include::dispatch::Vec<u8>'`